# Django CSS Background Image using STATIC_URL

Tags: css, django, sass, django-storage, django-statistics

I just changed my storage backend to Amazon S3, and I realized that my background was not loading for my site. I looked and realized that in my CSS (SASS actually) I had specified the background URL (`static/mysite/images/background.gif`).

I am wondering how I should fix this problem. Of course I *could* just change it to my new static URL, but that seems like a bad practice. So i tried loading my background image, with `{{ STATIC_URL }}`, in my `body` HTML, but then it renders my background first, before the `repeat: no-repeat;` renders on my actual CSS, causing the background to repeat across the whole screen while the CSS loads. Anyway I don't like mixing my styles into my document.

So what is the best way to provide a relative path for a background image in Django? Should I set up my CSS as a template, and direct to it through a view? That also seems messy.

Or should I just forget about making it static_url agnostic, and just hard code the thing in my CSS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Django compressor!](http://django_compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

It lets you render snippets of CSS directly inside your template that are ultimately combined into a single file OR you can even specify options to enable parsing of your CSS files with django's template engine and context: 
http://django_compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings/#django.conf.settings.COMPRESS_CSS_FILTERS

It's amazing and worth the trouble as you don't need to think about performance when managing CSS.

Comment: Woah! I was literally _just_ looking at that for static files compression, unrelated to this question! Thanks so much!

Comment: @saul.shanabrook hah! :) It's a great mature library.